# Flyway error reading UTF-8 file on Ubuntu 14.04 "Incorrect string value"

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, utf-8, character-encoding, flyway

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and flyway doesn't seem to be able to read my UTF-8 encoded SQL script.

I can run the sql script by using the terminal command

`mysql -u root -p my_db < v1_1__Test_migration_script.sql`

But when flyway runs it, I get the error `Incorrect string value:` on the file that is UTF-8 encoded.
My system has LANG set as en_US.UTF-8

Note that when flyway runs during setup on my Mac OSX machine it all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the database was using a different character set and collation.

A fix that worked for me was to specify it explicitly
`CREATE DATABASE my_db DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`